# Is it really necessary to configure bash when by default we have bash terminal in the vscode?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, plugins

By default vscode enables the bash in /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/media/shellIntegration-bash.sh then why most of the time we been directed to install external plugins?

I tried installing bash debug just because i did not know the power of the inbuilt bash shell.

Comment: that's just a shell integration script. it's not a Bash interpreter. neither am I aware of VS Code bundling UNIX commandline tools. what are you talking about?